# Add search engine context menu item to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to add a 'Search Google' function to the right-click context menu of a textarea? I would like to have the functionality whereby when one selects some text in a textarea, if you right-click it, you have a context entry that will allow you to search for that specific text in Google. This is much like the context menu entries you find in browsers when right clicking a page but focused to a textarea.

I see that there is a .contextmenu event https://api.jquery.com/contextmenu/ and I've been able to get an alert popup to pop when right-clicking in my textarea, but I'm looking rather for an additional entry to the default textarea menu that would be along the lines of "Search Google" and the event is `http://www.google.com/search?q=STSTST` where 'STSTST' is the selected text in the textarea and if you click that context menu entry, Google would be searched for the selected text.

Comment: i though that exists by default in all browsers!!

Comment: @MinaJacob Not in textareas.

Comment: the comment box is a text area https://66.media.tumblr.com/17a6e0c95c462b3b53e4c1e394b8c9ba/tumblr_of5w7t6k8j1vibctpo1_1280.png

Comment: @VAnton, at least Chrome does that in text areas, but Edge has its own right click feature.
You might try to replace the default behaviour, but then you need to create your own rightclick, and insert into Google's search query the selected text.

Comment: @MinaJacob IE and Edge do not do that.

Comment: make sense, might find "search bing for .."  :)

Comment: @AndreCanilho Yeah, it had crossed my mind to recreate all functionality from scratch plus add the search event. Would prefer to inject the functionality into the default context menu though.

Comment: @MinaJacob Ha ha, yeah. It doesn't though. And that's partly why I'm looking for a lead into creating this functionality, as I would in fact like to add multiple search engines - Google, Bing, Yahoo, DDG, etc. - to this textarea context menu.

Answer (score 4):

here is a demo 
http://codepen.io/mozzi/pen/EgZvjg

note: you shouldn't be asking this type of questions here, you should already have a solution but buggy! I found it interesting so I made a demo! :)

here is the core logic for the demo

```
$("#txtAboutMe").bind("contextmenu", function(event) {

  // Avoid the real one
  event.preventDefault();
  //alert(getSelectionText());
  selectedText = getSelectionText();
  $("[data-action='first']").text('Search Bing for "'+selectedText+'"');
  $("[data-action='second']").text('Search Google for "'+selectedText+'"');
  $("[data-action='third']").text('Search Yahoo for "'+selectedText+'"');
  // Show contextmenu
  $(".custom-menu").finish().toggle(100).

  // In the right position (the mouse)
  css({
    top: event.pageY + "px",
    left: event.pageX + "px"
  });
});
```

Comment: That is actually super helpful, Mina. Thanks. I'll be able to make good use of that I think. Thanks for the time.